# IRC ghost - how do I unghost and get back my original nick?

Tags: irc

When my IRC connection drops for whatever reason I am frequently logged back in as a ghost with the underscore after my registered nick.

What are the sequence of IRC commands to get logged back in as my original user when I am currently ghost?

If I just do `/msg NickServ identify user pwd` it says I am now identified for user but the channels still have me down as the ghosted user. How do I switch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You "ghost" a nick you own once you are identified as the same account as that nick with the following:

```
/msg nickserv ghost nickname
```

This will "ghost" (kill) your original nickname, which frees up that nick so you can do

```
/nick nickname
```

to change your nick again.

(In some networks (e.g. Freenode), you can use `/msg nickserv regain nickname` which does both actions at once.)

Comment: On irc.mozilla.org, I used `/msg nickserv recover nickname`.

Answer (score 2):

Preferred answer is actually wrong for oftc. The correct answer is:

```
/msg nickserv ghost <registered nick> <registered password>
```

You should then see a message somewhat like this:

```
>nickserv< ghost ****
* <registered nick> is now known as Guest4341
-NickServ- REGAIN succeed on nickname <registered nick>.  You have been changed to your nickname.
```

And that's it. Of course not every network has a service called "nickserv" so adjust to your network!